# How to create soap request in iOS with array parameter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, soap-client

I'm new on developing IOS using web service. Can anyone help me on how to create a request with array parameter in SOAP Web Service. In PHP I can create a request by doing this:

```
$params = array(
"authuserid" => "454",
"authpassword" => "");
$result = $client->call("EC_LOGON",$params);
```

please help me I'm having a hard time to find a good example how to apply that code in objective c programming.

Answer (score 1):

The SOAP message with parameters should be as follows,

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                             @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                             "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                             "<soap:Body>\n"
                             "<TestSoap xmlns=\"http://testsoap.com/\">\n"
                             "<parameterOne>%@</parameterOne >\n"
                             "<parameterTwo>%@</parameterTwo >\n"
                             "</TestSoap >\n"
                             "</soap:Body>\n"
                             "</soap:Envelope>\n", valueOne, valueTwo];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your app's code, you can post an string by appending all the objects of an array one after each other and separate them by any special character (like *), now in your PHP code you can make array with the same logic.

You can convert array to string from below code:

```
NSString *stringToPass;

for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++) {
    if ([stringToPass length])
    {
        stringToPass = [stringToPass stringByAppendingFormat:@"*%@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]]];
    }
    else
    {
        stringToPass = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[yourArray objectAtIndex:i]integerValue]]];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)

[Download HelloWorld Sample App](http://www.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/hello_soap1.zip)